# Independent parameters of a conformally invariant object depending on four points

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I was considering a conformally invariant object that depends on four points in space: $\Phi(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$. This object *apparently* depends on 16 different quantities (the four coordines of each of the four points), however since by hypothesis it is conformally invariant I argued that I could use conformal trasformations to fix 4 DoF with traslations, 6 DoF with Lorentz trasformations, 1 DoF with scale invariance and 4 more DoF with SCTs, however this adds up to 15, meaning $\Phi$ should depend only on one variable, while I know that there are two conformally invariant ratios: $u=\frac{x_{12}x_{34}}{x_{14}x_{23}}$ and $v=\frac{x_{12}x_{34}}{x_{13}x_{24}}$, therefore $\Phi(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = f(u, v)$.

Might this be that these two ratios are related?

Comment: You can't keep removing degrees of freedom independently when the generators don't commute. If you could, every dimension above 4 would have zero invariant four-point cross ratios.

Comment: Translations and rotations do not commute but I can absolutely remove DoF. In four-dimensional QFT this implies that only two of the three Mandelstam invariants are really independent.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that you can't remove any DoF. Just that you can't necessarily remove as many DoF's as generators.

Comment: Is there some kind of way of telling how many degrees of freedom one can remove?

Comment: The most general way I know is the framework of https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08987 where they talk about "dimension of the conformal moduli space".

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks :)